# Difference between `print(df['A'][2])` and `print(df.loc[2, 'A'])`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I Have a code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'B': [1, 2, 3]}, index=[0, 2, 3])

print(df['A'][2])

print(df.loc[2, 'A'])
```

Output:

```
bbb
bbb
```

**Question:** What is diffence between `print(df['A'][2])` and  `print(df.loc[2, 'A'])`? Does they mean exactly the same thing (just different syntax) or they can act differently in different situations? If they are different, what is exact difference?